# Returning a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I wish to return a promise that is dependent on other asynchronous requests. This is the best I came up with:

```
return Promise.all([user, name, fbprofile, phone])
    .then((results) => {
    return results[0].addUserAttributes([results[1], results[2], results[3]])
        .then((response) => response);
    });
```

It's three nested returns and all variables have been packed into an array. This makes the code hard to understand in my opinion.

Is there some way to achieve the same result without nesting functions?

Answer (score 3):

There is no "better" way, but a bit of deconstructing may add a bit of clarity. Also, the last `then` is useless.

```
return Promise.all([user, name, fbprofile, phone])
    .then(([userResult, ...otherResults]) =>
        userResult.addUserAttributes(otherResults)
    });
```

Comment: Cool, though, addUserAttributes is also a promise, I still don't need it?

Comment: You mean it returns a Promise? If so promises are chainable. The current function will return a promise fulfilling after the `Promise.all`  and the `userResult.addUserAttributes(...)` promise fulfilles.

Comment: supported in node 6 is worth noting!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to make this ecma6 but you should be able to just do the following:

```
//function to call once all are resolved.
function afterAllResolved(results){
   return results[0]
              .addUserAttributes(
                  [results[1], 
                   results[2],    
                   results[3])
}

return Promise
         .all([user, name, fbprofile, phone])
         .then(afterAllResolved);
```

This will call your function and return the result from the `results[0].add` as the resolved item.

Comment: addUserAttributes is also a promise, I still don't need the last callback?

Comment: The chain will still wait to resolve if you return a `then` that also returns a promise.  You don't need the last callback assuming you want to return the result from the `addUserAttributes` call.